# Windows, htcondor jobs are not running

Tags: condor

Im a new condor user running in windows, can you assist me im having a challenge in submitting my first job. In cmd i typed condor_store_cred add then entered my password then i granted access successfully the challenge now comes when i want condor to process a job im getting this error 
ERROR: Failed to open command file (No such file or directory) 
please help